# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty}(x-(\ln x)^3))$

Tags: limits

Here is my approach:
$\lim_{x\to \infty}(x-(\ln x)^3))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2-(\ln x)^6}{x+(\ln x)^3}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2}{x}=\infty$

I used the fact that $x^n$ goes faster to $\infty$ than $\ln x$.
Is my approach right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your method works with $n=1/3$. But in case it's not obvious any $n>0$ achieves $\ln x\in o(x^n)$, I'll flesh this out. Since $\int_0^\infty y^3e^{-y}dy=6<\infty$ has non-negative continuous integrand, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^3x}{x}=\lim_{y\to\infty}y^3e^{-y}=0$, i.e.$$\ln^3x\in o(x)\implies x-\ln^3x\sim x.$$So your limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Then for which $n$s this holds?

Comment: @soheil As I say, any $n>0$; you just replace $y^3$ with $y^{1/n}$, since $\Gamma(1+1/n)$ will still be finite.

Comment: I am not familiar with $\Gamma(1+1/n)$ I am not at this level :)

Comment: @soheil [Long story short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Motivation), it generalizes the observation $k!=\int_0^\infty y^ke^{-y}dy$ for integers $k\ge0$, as you can prove by induction.

Comment: It is interesting. thank you. I learned new things from your answer.

Comment: @J. G. what about notation $\ln x\in o(x^n)$? does it mean that $\ln x$ is error of $x^n$? Big O notation here means error or something else?

Comment: You do have to be careful that in general $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx$ being convergent does not imply $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ -- even if $f$ is positive.  The implication does hold if $f$ is eventually decreasing, which is the case for $f(y) = y^3 e^{-y}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct, although it is simpler to write
$$x-\ln(x)^3=x\left(1-\dfrac{\ln(x)^3}{x}\right)$$
and say that the fraction tends to $0$ for the reason you've mentioned.